# How to process multiple tasks in parallel and wait for success failure of each

Tags: java, threadpool, completable-future

I have around 5 tasks related to getting data from HTTP and processing and generating results based on the data.

I want to run these tasks in parallel and wait till all the tasks are completed successfully or one of them fail. Each task should be able to post failure reason. If one of the task fails then all are considered as failed and exit without waiting for all to complete.

I tried to implement it using completable future and list of futures, but it does not work and code is not good condition to post.

Is there any better way I can implement it? Example will help.

Comment: If the code is not "in good enough condition to post", transform it into good enough condition to post - that alone might fix the problem. Then, post the code. The `Future` approach seems very reasonable.

Comment: Without seeing your code it is hard to say why a `Future` approach isn't working. However, I can recommend trying to use an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for the tasks. If you find that one of the tasks fails then the Executor Service interface would let you terminate all the tasks.

Comment: @User7723337 Is your question resolved?

Answer (score 4):

Either use `allOf` static method or `Stream` approach.

**Approach 1:-**

```
CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture 
  = CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2, future3);

combinedFuture.get();
```

> static CompletableFuture    allOf(CompletableFuture... cfs)
>   Returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when all of the
>   given CompletableFutures complete.

In this approach, you need to get the results of Future object individually and perform further processing.

**Approach 2:-**

The advantage in approach 2 is that the Future results are concatenated and separated by single space assuming the Future returns String object.

```
String combined = Stream.of(future1, future2, future3)
  .map(CompletableFuture::join)
  .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

The best idea for running tasks in parallel is to use [Executor Service](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html) with [Completable Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html?is-external=true).
You have to consider exception handling if one task will fail.

Few possibilities are available in this case:

- use `exceptionally()`:

  ```
  QuoteUtil quoteUtil = new QuoteUtil();
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();

  CompletableFuture
          .supplyAsync(quoteUtil::emptyQuote, executor)
          .thenApply(String::length)
          .exceptionally(exception -> "No quote available")
          .thenAccept(System.out::println);

  executor.shutdown();
  executor.awaitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ```
- with exception handler:

  ```
  CompletableFuture
          .supplyAsync(quoteUtil::emptyQuote, executor)
          .thenApply(String::length)
          .handle((result, throwable) -> {
              if (throwable != null) {
                  return "No quote available: "
                          + throwable;
              } else {
                  return result.toString();
              }
          })
          .thenAccept(System.out::println);
  ```
- `thenApply()` exception:

  ```
  try {
      CompletableFuture
              .supplyAsync(quoteUtil::emptyQuote, executor)
              .thenApply(String::length)
              .thenAccept(System.out::println)
              .get();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
      executor.shutdown();
  }
  ```

Code snippets show just one call. You need to do the same but with a bunch of tasks. Build a list of tasks and pass to completable future, as suggested [notionquest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6337748/notionquest) at his answer. Or iterate over this list and call each task separately.